# Log to Dynatrace using Serilog and web.config .NET Framework API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-config, serilog, .net-4.8, dynatrace

I have a .NET Framework web api and I would like to configure the **web.config** file so the **Serilog** logger to log into **Dynatrace**.

My web.config file is like

```
  <appSettings>
     <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Information" />
     <add key="serilog:using:Dynatrace" value="Serilog.Sinks.Dynatrace" />
     <add key="serilog:write-to:Dynatrace:accessToken" value="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />
     <add key="serilog:write-to:Dynatrace:ingestUrl" value="https://pppp.live.dynatrace.com/api/v2/logs/ingest" />
```

Which is the correct configuration?

My Dynatrace configuration works in appsettings.json files. The problem is only in web.config.